# Searching for questions which are not closed

Tags: support, search

I am trying to search for questions on Stack Overflow which contain some specific text (e.g. "the setting name is") and belong to a particular language, (e.g. Java).

This works fine. However, can I add another filter to get only Open questions?

How do I perform all the actions in the same query?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just add `closed:no` to the query, such as [`[java] "setting name" closed:no`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[java]+"setting+name"+closed%3Ano+).

When you are on the search result page you can click on "*Advanced Search Tips*" on the right to see this syntax, and the full list of options in [Help Center - How do I search?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)